# How to uninstall Erlang using Homebrew in OSX 10.10?

Tags: macos, erlang, homebrew

I already installed Erlang in my OSX machine but I faced the below issues:

> /usr/local/bin/erl: line 28:
>   /Users/irshadpc/@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/erlang/17.5/lib/erlang/erts-6.4/bin/erlexec:
>   No such file or directory /usr/local/bin/erl: line 28: exec:
>   /Users/irshadpc/@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/erlang/17.5/lib/erlang/erts-6.4/bin/erlexec:
>   cannot execute: No such file or directory.

Can anyone help me to uninstall Erlang and re-install it?

Comment: What's wrong with `brew uninstall erlang`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To uninstall old versions of the formulas installed and see them while they are being uninstalled, just run:

```
brew cleanup -n
```

to uninstall erlang (if you are having troubles) just do

```
brew uninstall erlang --force
```

to install latest version of erlang after that

```
brew update
brew install erlang
```

Comment: Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool installed.
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.
When i tried your steps i got the above error